# Vue-Router: Globally Add Query Value to Routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

### Goal

I'd like to add `?instance=123` to every route that is generated.

### Problem

I've added a guard to append the value before navigating to each route, [but this approach](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) does not work as expected.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next({ query: { instance: '123' } });
});
```

How is this accomplished?

### ️‍♂️ Context

- "vue-router": "^2.5.3"
- "vue": "2.3.2",

Comment: Like this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/934#issuecomment-312477819

Comment: This exactly. And it works. Leave as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the code from [github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/934#issuecomment-312477819) posted by [codeofsumit](https://github.com/codeofsumit) seems to achieve what you want:

> ```
> router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {  
>   if (!to.query.instance) {
>     to.query.instance= '123';
>     next({ path: to.path, query: to.query });
>   } else {
>     next();
>   }
> });
> ```

What this does is adds the `instance` property to the query object, which is what you were doing in your attempt, but you were missing out the part where it has to call `next` with the modified object, otherwise it will just continue to the original route.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  to.query.instance = '123';
  next();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Update: When I `console.log(to);` right before `next()`, I can see the `instance` value has been correctly assigned. It just doesn't show up in the browser URL for some reason.

Comment: Why do you need to show `?instance=123` in every route? I thought it is strange to use beforeEach to change query value in every route.

Comment: It is unusual. I need to tie each browser tab (for this app) to a specific and unique localStorage instance. Similar in effect to using different Gmail accounts in different tabs. (The reason for the `instance` in the URL is to correctly persist the storage on refresh.)

Comment: @Donnie Why you don't use the the sessionStorage? The sessionStorage is unique for each browser tab. That should be the intended use.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, Marco. How did I miss that?! ‍♂️